# Which caulk around the sink in kitchen is a health-safe?

Tags: kitchens, safety, kitchen-sink, silicone

I need to glue a metal sink within the hole in the countertop - a gap has appeared in one place of contact-edge between the sink and top-counter. Many people have recommend silicone. My question is not about its strength and waterproof features.

I ask is the silicon based glue (or 100% silicon) SAFE to my health (being next to my plates and cups)?

Looking for your help, Michael.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You should [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know how to best participate here. Also, pictures of the problem area will help you to get a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

In general silicone is very safe for living organisms including humans. Cake molds, pacifiers and breast implants are made from silicone.

To my knowledge every single sink installed in a table is installed using a silicone caulk. I have never seen a gasket for that purpose.

Most carpenters and plumbers would use a silicone rated for wet rooms to install a sink. That means that they have some kind of anti-fungal agent in them. I don't know about the toxicity of such agents, unfortunately. However, do remember that mold is indeed unhealthy.

Comment: For all of the sinks I have replaced, I cursed the people who used silicone.

Comment: @Gunner: What is the alternative approach?

Comment: Once cured, unless you peel it up and serve it with your meal, you don't need to worry about silicone. It doesn't stay wet and sticky. Even latex caulk shouldn't rub off onto your dishes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to carefully read the label of whichever product you select. In general, pure silicone caulk **IS** food-safe, but some have chemicals (e.g. mold-resistant biocide) that make them unsuitable for food preparation areas.

The label will have markings (e.g. FDA) attesting to their suitability.

Comment: FDA = Food and Drug Administration